# Do electrons have sea electrons like protons have sea quarks

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Do electrons have sea electrons and other stuff like protons have sea quarks? As I understand it a proton is basically 3 quarks interacting via the EM, weak and strong interaction. If you describe the interactions with Feynman diagrams you get an infinite number of diagrams with all sorts of virtual particles.  Depending on the energy of the proton, some diagrams are more probable than others. For the proton a lot of them are quark/antiquark pairs and called sea quarks, but other virtuel particles also contribute. And if two protons collide, virtuel particles from one proton will interact with virtuel particles from the other proton and contribute to the outcome of the collision. First of all, is it correct what I have described here? Second of all, do you also get virtuel particles when you accelerate an electron, like electron/positron pairs?

Comment: To be sure, you're asking if an isolated elementary particle (electron) has something that a bound *system* of elementary particles (proton) has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your first question, this is roughly the idea but I have to emphasise that gluons play a big role, especially at small fractions of the proton momentum (indeed in proton-proton collisions at high energy, the protons are described by a set of probabilities to find a given constituent particle carrying a given fraction of the momentum).

As for an electron, not quite, but accelerated electrons can easily emit photons. For example at the $e^+ e^-$ collisioner LEP, collisions between real or quasi-real photons radiated by $e^+ e^-$ was a fun subject. But it becomes even more interesting as at those energies, the photons may oscillate in $q\bar{q}$ pairs, leading to collisions between a $\gamma$ and such a meson, or a collision between two such mesons. At the higher energy of the future International Linear Collider, such collisions will be even more significant. So to keep with the purity of the standard linguo, I would still answer your question by the negative but keeping in mind the rich phenomenology I have just brushed over.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the answer to your title question is no.

The quark "Sea" results from the fact that the protons is a composite particle, with 3 Valence quarks, and a collection of virtual quarks.

By contrast, because the electron has no known substructure, there is probably no scope for interactions that produce the equivalent sea of virtual particles.

Answer (score -1):

Second question's answer is yes you will get particles. For example, Electron–positron annihilation, you will get two photons. Actually by using two photons you can get one pair of electron-positron too.

First questions answer is detailed in here : https://en.0wikipedia.org/index.php?q=aHR0cHM6Ly9lbi53aWtpcGVkaWEub3JnL3dpa2kvRGlyYWNfc2Vh

For answer of the second question you can check this link also for more detail: https://en.0wikipedia.org/index.php?q=aHR0cHM6Ly9lbi53aWtpcGVkaWEub3JnL3dpa2kvRWxlY3Ryb27igJNwb3NpdHJvbl9hbm5paGlsYXRpb24